# Adding an Observable into a Observable<Collection<Class>>

Tags: java, collections, observable

I'm trying to make a collection of observables and then add an observable into that collection.

Right now in this code, it's saying `= new Observable<ArrayList<DMRegistration>>();` has protected access in rx.Observable and will not instantiate.

Also with `dmRegistrations.add(dmRegistration);` it complaining about `add`  saying that it cannot resolve method 'add(rx.Observable)'

I'm very new with observables and have Googled around but have found nothing that provided information leading to a possible solution. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

```
@Override
public Observable<Collection<DMRegistration>>getAllRegistrations() throws DMException{
    try{
        Observable<Collection<DMRegistration>> dmRegistrations = new Observable<ArrayList<DMRegistration>>();
        Observable<DMRegistration> dmRegistration = execute(get(baseUrl + "registrations"), DMRegistration.class);
        dmRegistrations.add(dmRegistration);
        return dmRegistrations;

    }catch(RestException e){
        throw new DMException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `Observable` different from the built-in Java `Observable`? I'm not sure what `rx` is...

Comment: 1. You have a typo in your code snippet: `new Observable<(ArrayList<DMRegistration>>();` see the extra `<`?
2. Which `Observable` are you using? `java.util.Observable` does not have a generic type, so...

Comment: rx is the import `import rx.Observable;`  http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html

Comment: Fixed that typo. Still the same problem though.

Comment: Where did `rx` come from? I'm not familiar with that package....

Comment: Can you modify `rx.Observable`? The compiler saying that `Observable`'s default constructor is not public. It's also saying that it cannot find a method with the signature `Observable#add(Observable)` (or something similar, I might not have gotten the generics exactly right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the `Observable` constructor has protected access, then you can't use it unless you're working in the `Observable` class or a subclass of `Observable`. So if you want to make this work with minimal changes you'll have to either make this class a subclass of `Observable` or make the constructor public, but depending on your situation that may or may not be possible.

The reason the compiler is complaining about being unable to resolve `add(rx.Observable)` is because it means exactly what it says. It can't find a method matching that combination of name/parameter in the `Observable` class. Could be because the way you have `Observable` parameterized, as it appears that `add()` is looking for a different type than you want to put in.

I'm making a bit of a guess here as to the structure of `Observable`, but the type of element that you're trying to add doesn't seem to match the type of element that `dmRegistrations` takes. You declared that `dmRegistrations` is `Observable<Collection<DMRegistration>>`, which (I assume) means that you're observing `Collection<DMRegistration>`. You're trying to add an object of type `Observable<DMRegistration>`, which isn't what `add()` is looking for, unless `Observable` implements `Collection`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me wrap my head around it a lot better. So you are saying there is no way to make this work unless I want to alter the rx.Observable class?

Comment: There is one other way to make this work, which is to make your class a subclass of `rx.Observable`